# Show/Hide text boxes in a <TABLE> based on radio button selection in a particular row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Please refer to the enclosed code for understanding. HTML Table is displayed with elements based on certain criteria. Whenever radio button in "Extra KM/Hr?" is Yes, then all columns onto its right hand side should be enabled, else disabled. I am populating the table values using PHP on this "displayTable" id.

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <!-- Title -->
        <title>Cab Tracker</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getRoutes(){ 
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#compName").change(function(){
                        var cID = $("#compName").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "loadTariff.php",
                            data:'companyID='+cID
                            }).done(function(data){
                            $("#displayTable").html(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/bootstrap4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/waves/waves.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/switchery/dist/switchery.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/DataTables/Responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/DataTables/Buttons/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/DataTables/Buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/dropify/dist/css/dropify.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/assets/css/core.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            .rating-outer span,
            .rating-symbol-background {
                color: #ffe000!important;
            }
            .rating-outer span,
            .rating-symbol-foreground {
                color: #ffe000!important;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/vendor/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css">
    </head>
    <body class="fixed-sidebar fixed-header content-appear skin-default">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="preloader"></div>
            <div class="site-overlay"></div>
            <div class="site-sidebar">
                <div class="custom-scroll custom-scroll-light">
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="with-sub">
                            <a href="#" class="waves-effect  waves-light">
                                <span class="s-caret"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
                                <span class="s-icon"><i class="ti-crown"></i></span>
                                <span class="s-text">Company</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="listcompanies.php">List Company</a></li>
                                <li><a href="addcompany.php">Add New Company</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="site-header">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                    <div class="navbar-left">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                            <div class="logo" style="background: url(/logo-black.png) no-repeat;"></div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="toggle-button dark sidebar-toggle-first float-xs-left hidden-md-up">
                            <span class="hamburger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="toggle-button-second dark float-xs-right hidden-md-up">
                            <i class="ti-arrow-left"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="toggle-button dark float-xs-right hidden-md-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1">
                            <span class="more"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-right navbar-toggleable-sm collapse" id="collapse-1">
                        <div class="toggle-button light sidebar-toggle-second float-xs-left hidden-sm-down">
                            <span class="hamburger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item hidden-sm-down">
                                <a class="nav-link toggle-fullscreen" href="#">
                                    <i class="ti-fullscreen"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-md-right">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown hidden-sm-down">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="avatar box-32">
                                        <img src="main/avatar.jpg" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right animated fadeInUp">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="">
                                        <i class="ti-user mr-0-5"></i> Profile
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="">
                                        <i class="ti-settings mr-0-5"></i> Change Password
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a href="logout.php" name="submit" class="dropdown-item">
                                        <span class="s-icon"><i class="ti-power-off"></i></span>
                                        <span class="s-text">Sign Out</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="site-content">
                <div class="content-area py-1">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" name="tariffset" action="settariff.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" onsubmit="return validateform()"> 
                            <div class="box box-block bg-white">
                                <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-md-3" style="width:15%">
                                        <label>Company:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6" style="width:80%">
                                        <?php
                                            require_once "config.php";

                                            $sqll = "select companyID,companyName from companymst where delFlag=0 order by companyName";

                                            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqll);

                                            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) 
                                            {
                                                    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC));

                                            }
                                        ?>                      
                                        <select id="compName" name="compName" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" required onChange="getRoutes();">
                                            <option selected value=-1>Select Company</option>
                                            <?php
                                                if (mysqli_num_rows($results) >0)
                                                {
                                                    foreach ($results as $row){
                                                        echo "<option value=$row[companyID]>$row[companyName]</option>";         
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br/>
                                <hr style="height: 2px;background: black; " >
                                <table id="editableTable" class="table table-bordered" >
                                    <thead style="text-align:center">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width='15%'><span>Route</span></th>
                                            <th width='20%'><span>Pickup/Drop</span></th>
                                            <th width='10%'><span># Days</span></th>
                                            <th width='10%'><span>Total Amount</span></th>
                                            <th width='20%'><span>Extra KM/Hr?</span></th>
                                            <th width='10%'><span>Allowed KM</span></th>
                                            <th width='10%'><span>Allowed Hr</span></th>
                                            <th width='10%'><span>Extra KM Rate</span></th>
                                            <th width='10%'><span>Extra Hourly Rate</span></th>                     
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="displayTable">
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <hr style="height: 2px;background: black; " >               
                                <br/>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit">
                                </div>              
                            </div>
                        </form>         
                    </div>
                </div>
                <footer class="footer">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row text-xs-center">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 text-sm-left mb-0-5 mb-sm-0">
                                <p>© 2020 S10Cabs</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/tether/js/tether.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/bootstrap4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/detectmobilebrowser/detectmobilebrowser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/jscrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/jscrollpane/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/jquery-fullscreen-plugin/jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/Responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/Buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/JSZip/jszip.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/Buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/Buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/DataTables/Buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/vendor/dropify/dist/js/dropify.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/assets/js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/assets/js/demo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/assets/js/tables-datatable.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main/assets/js/forms-upload.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/rating.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.rating').rating();
        </script>
        <script>
            function toggle(value){
                if(value=='hide'){
                    document.getElementById("allowedhr").setAttribute('disabled', true);
                    document.getElementById("allowedkm").setAttribute('disabled', true);
                    document.getElementById("extrahr").setAttribute('disabled', true);
                    document.getElementById("extrakm").setAttribute('disabled', true);              
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("allowedhr").removeAttribute('disabled');               
                    document.getElementById("allowedkm").removeAttribute('disabled');
                    document.getElementById("extrahr").removeAttribute('disabled');
                    document.getElementById("extrakm").removeAttribute('disabled');                 
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

TABLE is populated using the PHP code below:

```
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet)){
    $txtstr="";
    echo "<tr>
    <td style='width:30%'>" .$row["routeName"]. "</td>
    <td style='width:20%'>
        <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='pickup' checked value='Pickup' style='margin-left: 0px;margin-right:6px'>Pickup</label>
        <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='drop' checked value='Drop' style='margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 6px'>Drop</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' id='noofdays' value=".$row['noofdays']." name='noofdays' size='3'/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' id='pickupamt' value=".$row['pickupamt']." name='pickupamt' size='5'/>
    </td>
    <td style='width:20%'>";
        if ($row['extraallowed']==1){
            $txtstr = "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='SourceOfc' style='margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 6px' checked value='Yes' onclick=toggle('show')>Yes</label>";
            $txtstr.= "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='SourceOfc' style='margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 6px' value='No' onclick=toggle('hide')>No</label>";
        }
        else{
            $txtstr = "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='SourceOfc' style='margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 6px' value='Yes' onclick=toggle('show')>Yes</label>";
            $txtstr.= "<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='SourceOfc' style='margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 6px' checked value='No' onclick=toggle('hide')>No</label>";
        }
        echo $txtstr."</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='allowedkm' value=".$row['allowedkm']." name='allowedkm' size='5'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='allowedhr' value=".$row['allowedhrs']." name='allowedhr' size='5'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='extrakm' value=".$row['extrakmamt']." name='extrakm' size='5'/>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <input type='text' id='extrahr' value=".$row['extrahrsamt']." name='extrahr' size='5'/>
        </td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: As the PHP is not relevant to the issue could you please post the full HTML output so that a working example of the problem can be created.

Comment: `onclick=toggle('show')` implies that you have a function named `toggle`. Is that the case?

Comment: `onclick=toggle('hide')` also needs proper quoting for some browsers, like `onclick="toggle('hide')"`